# How does Authorize.Net Silent Post work?

Tags: e-commerce, authorize.net, silent-post

Authorize.net offers a "Silent POST" feature for their Automated Recurring Billing. It's supposed to POST data to a url of your choosing, telling you whether they were able to charge the customer, how much, etc. The problem is, it isn't very well documented.

- Is there any way to test a post to that URL? I've signed up for a developer account, but there's no way to specify that URL like you could in the actual system. Hence, there doesn't seem to be a way to test it out.
- If not, is there a list of possible values it could return? It appears to send `x_first_name`, `x_amount` - I've seen code that uses those values - but since I can't actually get it to send a response, I'm not sure.
- Is there documentation for this feature anywhere? Or even class that implements it fully?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Better late then never: [All About Authorize.Net’s Silent Post](http://www.johnconde.net/blog/all-about-authorize-nets-silent-post/)

Comment: I recently contacted Auth.net about some missing silentPosts and learned two things from the supervisor I talked to:
1) Auth.net does not check response codes for their silentPosts
2) Auth.net does not log anything for silentPosts except "error codes" (of which there were none)

This means that silentPost is not reliable (and hence, should not be used). Instead check for transaction manually using the transaction details API http://developer.authorize.net/api/transaction_details/

Comment: is there any silent post url implementation using Spring java or just java ?

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen much on it only for AIM and SIM, you might just give them a call.

Comment: Okay - information on Silent POST for AIM is probably somewhat similar, so if you can point me to that, that's helpful too.

Comment: You can find most everything on this page http://developer.authorize.net/guides/, including (as I just found) information on the reacurring payments, in the section titled 'Automated Recurring Billing – Application Programming Interface (API) Guide'

Answer (score 0):

Log in to your Authorize.Net order processing account, and click on the Settings link (under ACCOUNT, in the left column). Then click on the "Silent Post URL" link in the Transaction Format Settings area. You can enter your silent post URL on the next page. The next page also contains a link to the documentation explaining the technical details. HTH

Answer (score 0):

Here's a few more (somewhat) useful posts I found on the subject.

- [Merchant Account Services](http://www.merchant-account-services.org/blog/handling-authorizenet-arb-subscription-failures/) - gives some limited sample code (PHP)
- [Experts Exchange](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Q_22138459.html) - lists a few helpful variables, gives an idea of what's being sent (ASP).

Answer (score -1):

You still have to call your account rep for them to activate Silent Post URL with your account because that is not something that is enabled automatically

Comment: That's not true. As mentioned you can activate it in your control panel.

Answer (score -1):

Our clients use the following tool to test silent post url requests sent from the Authorize.Net gateway.

Simply add the following url to your silent post settings and change the email address for the results to be delivered to an email of choice.

**URL:**

http://www.silentposturl.com/action/email/index.php?support@silentposturl.com